# Header in All Pages Including First Page with Title

Tags: header-footer, titles

I have a Word document as the following:

[image: 1]

As it can be seen, I have a header with some information in the right and my univesity logo on the left. There is a thick black line that divides the header from the rest of the text, and on this page, the title appears.

I have tried to replicate this format into LaTEX with zero success; I've even asked ChatGPT for help, who pointed me out to use the package *fancyhdr*. I tried several configurations but none gave me the same format.

I'm using the following base text, which includes all of the packages I need:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm,top=1cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathptmx} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{times} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{amsmath} % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{amssymb}  % assumes amsmath package installed

\title{Title}
\author{Subtitle}
\date{Subsubtitle}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle

    Body...

\end{document}
```

I would appreciate any help into trying to fit this format into LaTEX.

Comment: You can customize the `\maketitle`.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but it's best to cut down on packages in your preamble whenever you can. It makes it easier to read your own code, and additionally, it makes it easier for us to help you :) For instance, you load `amsmath` and `amssymb` multiple times, and you load `mathptmx` and `times`, both of which do the same thing and both of which are obsoleted by `newtxmath`/`newtxtext`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code below. I would suggest increasing `top` in geometry to something greater than 1 cm, just so that there's enough space at the top of the document for your logo. If your logo is too big, then it'll cause the header to edge into the title of your document.

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mwe}

\fancypagestyle{custom-first-page}{ 
  \lhead{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{your-uni-logo.png}}
  \rhead{Info 1\\Info 2\\Info 3}
}

\title{\bfseries Title}
\author{\bfseries Subtitle}
\date{\bfseries Subsubtitle}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{custom-first-page}

The body text
\end{document}
```

[image: The header of the first page of a document. A placeholder for the university logo is on the left, and there are three lines of placeholder text on the right. A title with a subtitle and subsubtitle in bold text are shown below.]

Comment: Worked perfectly! MVP